# HandleBars Paginate in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pagination

I am trying to paginate my records using the handlebars-paginate middleware to achieve this. I want to be able to display 20 records per page and I have done below:

Inside the entry point js (app.js), I registered this helper
Handlebars.registerHelper('paginate', paginate);

**My Controller**

```
const perPage = 20
const page = req.query.p

     Customer.find({})
            .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
            .limit(perPage)
            .lean()
        .exec(function (err, customers) {
            Customer.countDocuments().exec(function (err, count) {
                if (err) {
                    req.flash('error_msg', 'Something happened while trying to process this request. Please try again...')
                    return res.redirect('/account/dashboard')
                }

                res.render('restricted/dashboard', {
                    layout: 'dashboard_layout',
                    pagination: {
                        page: req.query.p || 1,
                        pageCount: perPage
                    },
                    customers,
                    page_title: 'Dashboard'
                })
            })
        })
```

**My HandleBar View Pagination area**

```
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
            <ul class="paginate">
                {{#paginate pagination type="first"}}
                    <li {{#if disabled}} class="pageNumber disabled" {{/if}}><a href="?p={{n}}">First</a></li>
                {{/paginate}}

                {{#paginate pagination type="previous"}}
                    <li {{#if disabled}} class="pageNumber disabled" {{/if}}><a href="?p={{n}}">Prev</a></li>
                {{/paginate}}
```

So I noticed that when there are no records in other pages, there are still some pagination links that showed even with no records. I have attached the screenshot[image]

```
                {{#paginate pagination type="middle" limit=pagination.pageCount}}
                    <li {{#if active}} class="pageNumber active" {{/if}}><a href="?p={{n}}">{{n}}</a></li>
                {{/paginate}}
                
                {{#paginate pagination type="next"}}
                    <li {{#if disabled}} class="pageNumber disabled" {{/if}}><a href="?p={{n}}">Next</a></li>
                {{/paginate}}

                {{#paginate pagination type="last"}}
                    <li {{#if disabled}}class="pageNumber disabled" {{/if}}><a href="?p={{n}}">Last</a></li>
                {{/paginate}}
            </ul>
        </div>
```

[image]

Can anyone point out what I need to do so that those extra links without records don't show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendering the handlebars template, you're using `perPage` constant, which is 20, as `pageCount`

```
   pageCount: perPage
```

Then in the handlebars template :

```
   {{#paginate pagination type="middle" limit=pagination.pageCount}}
```

That's why you have 20 pages all the time.

Because you already count the number of document, the page limit should be: `Math.ceil(totalDocument/perPage)`

In your code, replace :

```
 pageCount: perPage
```

by :

```
pageCount : Math.ceil(count/perPage)
```

Comment: You just saved a soul. Thanks